# How to read static files from jar useing Spring MVC?

Tags: java

How can I use spring mvc to read static files from jar, I used

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="classpath*:/static"/>;
```

, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it must use `classpath`, not `classpath*`, when using classpath, spring will make it as `ClassPathResource` not as `ServletContextResource` as usual.